# The division algebras arising in the Wedderburn decomposition of a finite group modulo its radical in characteristic $p$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, group-rings

The following question is probably straightforward for those who know.  However, I am used to working either over splitting fields or in characteristic zero.

> > **Question.**  Let $G$ be a finite group and $k$ a field of characteristic $p>0$.  The quotient $kG/rad(kG)$ decomposes as a direct product of matrix rings over division algebras, finite dimensional over $k$.  What can be said about these division algebras? If $D$ is one of these division algebras, is it true that $p$ does not divide the dimension of $D$ over its center?

I sort of convinced myself that in fact these division algebras must be fields in characteristic $p$ (and hence what I want is true), but since I couldn't find this stated anywhere, I suspect there is a flaw in my logic.  Anyway, here is my "proof". Please let me know where it goes astray.

Let $F_p$ be the field with $p$ elements.  Then $F_pG/rad(F_pG)$ is a separable algebra because $F_p$ is perfect.

Claim. $kG/rad(KG)\cong k\otimes_{F_p}(F_pG/rad(F_pG))$.

Pf.   Note that $k\otimes_{F_p}(F_pG/rad(F_pG))=  kG/(k\otimes_{F_p}rad(F_pG))$.  But since $F_pG/rad(F_pG)$ is separable, we have that $k\otimes_{F_p}(F_pG/rad(F_pG))$ is semisimple.  As $k\otimes_{F_p}rad(F_pG)$ is a nilpotent ideal, we conclude that it is $rad(kG)$.

Since finite division rings are fields and $F_p$ is perfect, we have that $F_pG/rad(F_pG)\cong \prod_{i=1}^m M_{n_i}(L_i)$ where the $L_i$ are finite separable extensions of $F_p$.  Thus by the claim $kG/rad(kG) = k\otimes_{F_p}(F_pG/rad(F_pG))=\prod_{i=1}^m M_{n_i}(k\otimes_{F_p}L_i)$.  But since the $L_i$ are finite separable extensions, each $k\otimes_{F_p}L_i$ is a finite product of separable extensions of $k$.

I guess if there is a mistake here, it is in the claim.

Comment: My understanding of this topic is not perfect, but I think that your proof is correct, and that the result is essentially Exercise (9.7) Page 157 of Isaacs' Character Theory of Finite Groups.

Comment: @DerekHolt,  I don't have Isaacs book, which was where I wanted to look. Thanks.

Comment: Although this may not technically be a research level problem, in practice there would probably be many more people who read mathoverflow who would have the necessary expertise to answer this properly.

Comment: Hi I have a question to the last line of the proof: If one takes a finite and hence separable field $L_i$ and an arbitrary (not necessary separable, but (semi-)simple) field K why is the tensor product $K\otimes L_i$ like you described it? I know that a tensor product of a separable and semisimple algebra is again semisimple (e.g. in the book of Curtis/Reiner). Thanks for commend as this proof is related to the question when a group algebra is a reduced algebra:-)

Comment: If $L_i$ is a finite separable extension of $F$ and $K$ is any extension of $F$, then by the primitive element theorem $L_i\cong F[x]/(p(x))$ where $p(x)$ factors into linear factors over the algebraic closure of $F$.  Then $K\otimes L_i\cong K[x]/(p(x))$ and $p(x)$ still has distinct roots in the algebraic closure of $K$ (which contains an algebraic closure of $F$ which will have the roots of $p(x)$).  The general case follows because a separable extension is a direct limit of finite separable extensions.

Comment: I have another question to your Claim that $KG/rad(KG)\cong K\otimes_{F_p} (F_pG/rad(F_pG))$. The left side is finite-dimensionl the right side could be infinite dimensional if $K$ is choosen to be an infinite field of $char(K)=p$ with prime-field $F_p$.

Comment: Tensoring a fd vector space with an extension field K results in a K-vector space of the same dimension as a K-vector space as the original had over the ground field.

Comment: Yes, indeed, so in the claim the isom. is viewed as $K$-algebras. From this one can deduce the $K$-dimension of $KG/rad(KG)$ is precisely the $F_p$-dimension of $F_pG/rad(F_pG)$ and in other words for every fields $K,L$ of characteristic $p$ the $K$-dimension of $KG/rad(KG)$ and $L$-dim. of $LG/rad(LG)$ are equal. Thats very nice.

Comment: Just a comment: This theorem is proven at the beginning of Finite groups II by Huppert and Blackburn.

Comment: It is true that an infinite field can be replaced by a finite subfield in Benjamin's question. Hence the result follows since a finite division ring is a field. See Section 7 of my joint paper MR1380609 with Laci Kovács.

Comment: Under what circumstances would $k \otimes_{F_p} L_i$ be Galois over $k$?